# Cannot append a link to ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is the Html returned from an ajax

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group clearfix">

           SOmething Other not important
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="linkDelte">d</div>
</div>
```

When I make this ajax request I want to append a link to the div 'linkDelete'

```
$('#addResourceMineral').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        dataType: 'html',
        url: '@Url.Action("AddResourceMineral", "Application")'
    }).success(function (partialView) {
        alert(partialView);
        var result = $(partialView).find("#linkDelte").append('a href="#">Link</a>');

        $('#resourceMineralDiv').append(partialView);

    });
});
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: Are you still struggling for the solution ?

Comment: No I found one way!  But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below code. Instead of appending `partialView`, append the `result` object.

```
$('#addResourceMineral').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        dataType: 'html',
        url: '@Url.Action("AddResourceMineral", "Application")'
    }).success(function (partialView) {
        var result = $(partialView).find("#linkDelte").append('a href="#">Link</a>');

        $('#resourceMineralDiv').append(result);

    });
});
```

Comment: The problem is that I would have another divs with the same id and  i want to add this link only to this response. In your case it finds the first element with that id and adds the link only to this element